# In C, how can you get an int with leading zeros?

Tags: c, unsigned

I need to generate a pin number, between 0 and 9999;

0's are important since I'm gonna use this pin to encrypt some files, and encrypting with '0024' is different than encrypting with '24'

I'm using an unsigned int and it's isn't working..

Is the only way an array?

Comment: you can use character type array ....

Comment: E.g: Use `%04d` with your `printf` `sprintf`

Comment: isn't that just a matter of representation?

Comment: You are confusing how you are storing the information and how you will be using it.

Comment: @glglgl No, it is not, as I said, 0024=/=24 if I use it as an encryption key

Comment: You need to specify the part of the algorithm where "encrypting with '0024' is different than encrypting with '24'" because that is not obvious.  I would guess that you're encrypting in phases or a loop once per digit in the PIN, but that's just a guess.  If you're just using the PIN *value* as an encryption key, then 0024 is exactly the same as 24 (and that would be a terrible way of doing it!)

Comment: @LPs that should work as a way to show it, but I can't really use it in the encrypt function, thanks anyway

Comment: @PeteB , I tried encrypting with openssl the same file with the key 0024 and 24 and then used the "diff" on both files and I got differences.. are you absolutely sure that is the same?

I'm using AES256, and why is it a terrible way? It is not supposed to be strong, it's a school project where we specifically have to encrypt with a 4 digit number pin. (We should add a "3 chances only" method on the decryption tho)

Comment: How do you pass "0024" to your function? With a string?

Comment: I would say that openssl definitely does not use the PIN *value* as the encryption key.  To be clear, when I say 'value' I'm talking about the integer number represented by the PIN as a whole.

Comment: @LPs I do not yet, since I can't obtain the leading zeros, but I would prefer to pass it as an integer, but that ain't possible..

Comment: Looking at http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/12/12/simple-file-encryption-with-openssl/ it looks like openssl takes an encryption key which is a string.  You should do the same with your PIN.

Comment: @PeteB I think you're right...

Comment: Then you can use `sprintf` to make your key as string with `%04d` and then pass it to your encryption function.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. An `int` is an integer, and for integers it really doesn't make sense to talk about leading zeros. They don't exist, an integer (in the mathematical sense, which is what `int` is trying to model on a computer) basically cannot have leading zeros. See comments for more pedantry about this, I tried to simplify it reasonably but might have failed since I'm just a lowly programmer and not a mathematician.

All the bits available for the `int` are used to store actual value bits, none are available to store that kind of representational information.

It sounds as if you want a string, or an array of digits.

Comment: To be pedantic, one might say that integers have an infinite amount of leading zeros. ;-)

Comment: @The111  Yay pedantry! Me too! If we're going to be pedantic an integer has no concept of leading zeroes, only (decimal) notation has this concept, where there is no one-to-one correspondence between an integer and its notations; in fact, one integer can be denoted in countably infinite many ways using the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your integer value as a string and do formatting so it will return integer with leading zero in string format.